# How is quantum function $f(x) = a^x \mod N$ constructed in Shor's algorithm?

Tags: quantum-computing

I can't see how I can apply quantum function $a^x\mod N$ to initial states. Explanations of Shor's algorithm often skips this part, and I do not see what unitary matrix this algorithm would correspond to.

reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Shor%27s_algorithm

Comment: note that this part can be done classically. See the separation to classical/quantum steps in https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Shor%27s_algorithm. Furthermore, whatever can be done classically, can be done quantumly, not?

Answer (score 1):

[This paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0511) by Pavlidis and Gizopoulos walks through one possible construction of the circuit you're looking for and also provides references to other literature on the subject:

"Fast Quantum Modular Exponentiation Architecture for Shor's Factorization Algorithm". Archimedes Pavlidis, Dimitris Gizopoulos.  http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0511

Answer (score 1):

[Remarks on Quantum Modular Exponentiation and Some Experimental Demonstrations of Shor’s Algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.6252) is a good survey on this topic.

I have found two perspective to this problem.

1. we can calculate the modular exponentiation in the classical computer, which tells us how to create the $x^{2^i} (mod\ N)$ gate. That is, we can view the modular exponentiation as oracle.
2. the modular exponentiation gate is implemented in the quantum circuit. One design is shown in [Fast Quantum Modular Exponentiation Architecture for Shor's Factorization Algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0511), where at least $1600 L^3$ gates are needed with $L = \log(N)$.

Anyway, the modular exponentiation is harder than QFT. In some design of the modular exponentiation, multiple QFT's are used.

Comment: The first perspective is not correct.  It's not enough for it to be an oracle; we need it to be a linear operation, so you can apply it to a superposition of values for $x$ and obtain a corresponding superposition of values for $x^a \bmod N$.  Instead, what you should be saying in your first bullet point is that it can be implemented in a classical computer, so by standard results, it can be implemented in a quantum computer as well.

Comment: @D.W. Thanks for your comment! Please check whether there is something wrong in my following statement. For a given $i$, we can know from the classical computer that the $x^{2^i} (mod\ N)$ gate should map $0, 1$ into $1, x^{2^i} (mod\ N)$ respectively. Thus, we can just prepare the linear quantum controlled $x^{2^i} (mod\ N)$ gate: $|q,1\rangle \to |q, x^{q*2^i} (mod\ N)\rangle$ for $q \in \{0,1\}$ as an oracle. Totally, there are $O(L)$ such oracles.

Comment: That would look correct to me if you had left for the part where you write "as an oracle".  I think you want to use this as part of a quantum circuit, not as an oracle.  I agree that you can precompute $x^{2^i} \bmod N$ on a classical computer; then your quantum circuit can use a quantum controlled gate, and you can multiply the results of those (in a quantum circuit for multiplication). But I think it's a quantum circuit you want, rather than an oracle.

Answer (score -1):

The algorithm uses the functional superposition s of f. A state with 2q qubits (2<sup>q</sup>=Q, where Q is the same as in the Wikipedia article):

s(xy) = Q<sup>-1/2</sup> where y = f(x), else 0

You can see xy as the concatenation of x and y in binary form. x and y run from 0 to Q-1.

Here is how it can be done with q ancillary qubits (3q qubits total):

- Start with 3q qubits in the zero state (1,0,0,...). I'll call the first q qubits x, the second q qubits y and the third q qubits z

  Apply the Hadamard transform to x

  Follow x to y with CNOT. This yields the state s(xyz) = Q<sup>-1/2</sup> where x = y and z = 0, else 0

  Apply f'(x,y) = (x,f(x) XOR y) to y and z. f' is invertible and has a unitary matrix. This yields the state s(xyz) = Q<sup>-1/2</sup> where x = y and z = f(x), else 0

  Apply g(x,y) = (x,x XOR y) to x and y. This yields the state s(xyz) = Q<sup>-1/2</sup> where y = 0 and z = f(x), else 0

  Swap x and y with swap gates. This yields the state s(xyz) = Q<sup>-1/2</sup> where x = 0 and z = f(y), else 0. x is in the zero state (1,0,0,...) and can be separated from yz - which forms the functional superposition of f