# Matrix for modular exponentiation in Shor's algorithm

Tags: quantum-computing

I'm trying to simulate Shor's algorithm with a model using vectors for quantum registers and matrices for quantum gates, however I'm stuck at the modular exponentiation bit of Shor's algorithm, having no idea how to build the corresponding matrix (unlike Hadamard and QFT). How can I build said matrix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is quantum function $f(x) = a^x \mod N$ constructed in Shor's algorithm?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43805/how-is-quantum-function-fx-ax-mod-n-constructed-in-shors-algorithm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that Shor's algorithm doesn't require modular exponentiation. All you need is (controlled) modular *multiplication*.

There are two steps to getting the matrix for modular multiplication:

1. Write a function to turn any permutation into a matrix.
2. Apply it to the permutation $a \rightarrow a \cdot k \pmod{r}$.
3. *(Optional) Instead of making that matrix and multiplying by it, save massive execution time by just applying the permutation directly.*

For step 1, just have a function like this:

```python
import numpy as np

def make_permutation_matrix(n, permutation):
    r = np.zeros((n, n))
    for i in range(n):
        r[permutation(i), i] = 1
    return r
```

Then for step 2, use it:

```python
import math
k = pow(base, exponent, modulus)
n = math.ceil(math.log(modulus, 2))
mul_matrix = make_permutation_matrix(
    2**n,
    permutation=lambda x: x*k % modulus)
```